# Error when using selectRaw() Laravel method with parameter binding

Tags: php, laravel, binding, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to run this: `$query->selectRaw('count(?)', [$column])` on Laravel 7.0, but gives me an error:
`SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1`.

PS: `$column` is a string.

When I put `count(distinct ?)`, it results in wrong count.

I already tried `"{$column}"` and `'%'.$column.'%'`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the whole query and the logic of getting count based on distinct column? and what values are expected in `$column`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I already move on, I don't have the code anymore, but it was a generic method in my repository that receiving the `$column` (as the name says, it's the column name) and include the count in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried other ways for hours, until I ask in a community and someone answered me that it's not possible to do this. The binding will only works with column values or something like that, despite that it doesn't have detailed uses of the selectRaw method.

Well, I've lost many hours, so I gave up and went to my objective with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use param in **selectRaw** by using **quotes**

Example:

```
$column = 1;
$query->selectRaw('count(**$column**)');
```